# "Error: We are currently unable to download the log. Please try again later." when trying to load github action log

Tags: github, github-actions

I currently have a GitHub action that runs yarn list after a tag is created. I have been able to see the logs up until today (I created the action last week). the action runs successfully, but when I go to see the log of each run, it gives the "Error: We are currently unable to download the log. Please try again later." There have been about 60 tag creations since I implemented the action. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

There are currently issues with GitHub Actions that degrade the experience.

You can always view the current status at https://www.githubstatus.com/.

[image: Showing the GitHub Status Page]

Comment: I visited the website you provided and everything is okai but I still have the same error.

Comment: Not helpful, github status says "All Systems Operational" but I'm unable to see my Actions' logs