# Error: We are currently unable to download the log. Please try again later

Tags: github-actions

On github actions logs I get the above error when attempting to view the logs. I already tried 'again later'. I've seen this error again and again over the past few months.

[image]

I found this related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68670027/error-we-are-currently-unable-to-download-the-log-please-try-again-later-wh) advising to check status at https://www.githubstatus.com/.

Everything is green there for me just now:
[image]

I need to see the logs because there's been a problem with my workflow, I need to see what has happened. How can I see the logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that log retention is the same setting as artifact retention. My artifacts are only stored for one day and this applies to log too.